# Cannot redeclare ::shouldReceive() when testing Facade

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, facade

According to the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/testing#mocking-facades), I should be able to mock a facade via `Object::shouldReceive()`, but when I do it says I cannot redeclare the method.  The view works correctly when I view it in my browser, I just need to figure out how to test this correctly.

`Cannot redeclare Mockery_1_Facades_MyService::shouldReceive() in /path-to-project/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(16) : eval()'d code on line 672`

Here's my test:

```
public function testSend()
{
    MessageService::shouldReceive('find')->once()->with(1);

    $this->call('GET', '/message/1/send');

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('message.index');
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
public function send($id)
{
    $message = MessageService::find($id);
    $this->messageService->sendBroadcast($message);

    return Redirect::route('message.index')
        ->with('message', "Sending message: {$message->name}, stand by...");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to mock already mocked class. See if you have registered your service somewhere as a facade - Laravel has a lot of auto generated defaults, which is hard to notice. Here is a facades **shouldReceive** method:

```
public static function shouldReceive()
    {
    $name = static::getFacadeAccessor();

    if (static::isMock())
    {
        $mock = static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
    }
    else
    {
        $mock = static::createFreshMockInstance($name);
    }

    return call_user_func_array(array($mock, 'shouldReceive'), func_get_args());
    }
```